# Reset form.submit to its original state jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have simple form. I changed form submit - something like this.

```
$("#formID").submit(function () { do something; return false; });
```

How do I reset submit back to its original state after this, because if data is valid I need to post it back to another url.

Comment: What do you mean by "reset submit back to its original state"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8g2j9/)**

To remove the submit event, you could use ***[`unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)***:

```
$('#formID').unbind("submit");
```

which would remove the defined submit event and callback.

Answer (score 0):

Use a hidden button with your regular submit code.

And the after returning from the code above, click the hidden button